# 'PKAddressField' is deprecated: first deprecated in iOS 11.0 - Use PKContactField and -requiredShippingContactFields / -requiredBillingContactFields

Tags: swift, stripe-payments, passkit

I am getting this warning in default files like STPAddress.h how to resolve that warning. how to write correct way of deprecated with PKContactField. This is the warning :
[image]

How to resolve that one

Comment: Did you try the suggestion of the compiler?

Comment: i tried but it says the same warning after i modified the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Stripe iOS SDK? Could you try updating to [v12.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200-2018-01-16) if you aren't already using at least this version?

See migration [instructions here](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/MIGRATING.md#migrating-from-versions--1200).

These warnings should be caused because the framework is using old methods to maintain support back to iOS 8. Changes to silence the warnings should have been included in [v11.5.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1150-2017-11-09) (change #823) and a migration to `STPContactField` was made in [v12.0.0](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#1200-2018-01-16) (change #848 - minimum iOS version 9)